# What advantages my BO deves gets in case of using EF with SQL Server having all relationships maintained?

Tags: entity-framework

I am a DBA. I want to know what advantages my Business Objects developers will get when using EF with SQL Server DB which is fully managed using Foreign keys and Primarkey as and when require. As this is our new project and we have to use EF with SQL Server 2008 R2. We have a plan to use Database First Approach. Can anyone tell me what difference my Business Object developer will experience in case If I define all foreign Key relationships in my DB?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's setup correctly, when your developers actually create their objects from the database structure, they'll be able to access any related tables rather easily.

It should also make creation of new objects (rows in the tables) easy, as it then shouldn't be possible to create new items that would break the foreign key relationship.

It's also just plain good practice to correctly setup any foreign keys in the database; I'm not sure of any benefit not to.

As a developer that's had to work with data sources that haven't been setup correctly, I can tell you a correctly setup database structure is an amazing experience for a developer.

(As an aside, as a DBA, you may want to take a look at EF. Also take a look at LINQ, one of the items that they'll be using. In particular, [Why LINQ beats SQL](http://www.linqpad.net/WhyLINQBeatsSQL.aspx) may help you get a basic understanding, even if you don't agree with the article title :) )